# Open word template and save as

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm using C# to read data from a CSV file and update the values of bookmarks in a word document.  I have it working, however, I want it to open the template file, update it and save it under another name.

I used this code:

```
_Application word = new Application();
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(@"D:\Documents\Bookmarked.dot");
doc.Bookmarks["mybookmark"].Select();
word.Selection.TypeText("Replacement text");
((_Application)word).Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges, WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat);
```

From here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/csharpgeneral/thread/32b25cfd-cc5b-4e9f-bcbf-0dbbd49bca02

I just don't know how to save it under another name.

Comment: `SaveAs`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object paramMissing = Type.Missing;
object fileFormat = wdSaveFormat.[whatever you want]
object filenameOut = @"c:\somefile.extension";

doc.SaveAs(ref filenameOut, ref fileFormat,
              ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
              ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, 
              ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, 
              ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing);
```

Some info and examples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305.aspx

Comment: sorry, i wrote the wrong variable name in my answer. I'll edit it for others.